# Convert decimal values in array to percentages and pass all values into graph

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

I am trying to convert an array from decimals to percentages in order to display the points as percentages in my graph (chart.js). Below is my array.

[image]

I am mapping over my data and have:

```
.map((i) => {
const name = Object.keys(i.models)[0];
const trainingInit = i.models[name].metrics.train_binary_accuracy
```

I have tried the below:

```
const arrayNumbers = () => {
   const myStringArray = trainingInit;
   const arrayLength = myStringArray.length;
   for (let x = 0; x < arrayLength; x++) {
        console.log(myStringArray[x] * 100);
   }
};
```

This console logs the array as percentages.

[image]

I cannot pass this data into the chart, I have tried to return the value (replace console.log with return but I only get the first point)

Here is the chart dataset data.

```
datasets: [
   {
      label: 'Training',
      data: yAxisValue.length !== 0 ? yAxisValue : [arrayNumbers()],
      fill: false,
      borderColor: 'rgb(0, 119, 182)',
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(0, 119, 182)',
   },
```

This is the closest I've got. As you can see only one point appears.

[image]

Appreciate any help.

this worked.

```
const arrayNumbers = () => {
     const myStringArray = trainingInit;
     const arrayLength = myStringArray.length;
     const newArray = [];
     for (let x = 0; x < arrayLength; x++) {
         newArray.push(trainingInit[x] * 100);
     }
     return newArray;
};
```

Comment: _“I have tried to return the value (replace console.log with return but I only get the first point)”_ - well of course, because the first call to return makes it leave your function already. You need to put your modified values into an array first, and then return that complete array at the end.

Comment: (And `[arrayNumbers()]` would need to be just `arrayNumbers()` then, unless you really need an array wrapped inside an array in this position.)

Comment: Hi CBroe, thanks for taking time to help out. I have tried to push myStringArray[x] * 100 into a new array but getting back 1. Think I'm using the wrong approach. const newArray = []; const points = myStringArray[x] * 100; console.log(newArray.push(points));

Comment: _“but getting back 1”_ - from the console.log statement, you mean? Well of course you do, because the return value of the [`push` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push#return_value) is the new _length_ of the array. If you want to check what your array actually contains now - then you need to push the value into it first, and then log _the array_ to console.

Comment: Hi CBroe, yes the console.log. You're putting me through my paces here :). I don't know how to push the value into it first: const points = newArray.push(myStringArray[x]); ?. Thanks for all your help so far.

Comment: _Just_ call the push method, you don’t need to assign the return value to anything (unless you are particularly interested in that specifically.) `newArray.push(…); console.log(newArray);`

Comment: ok, so, const newArray = [];  newArray.push(myStringArray[x] * 100); console.log(newArray); brings back each point as a percentage but in individual arrays. They would need to be in one array to display in the graph?

Comment: Well then _put_ them all in the same array.

Comment: I have no clue how to do that. I though newArray.push(myStringArray[x] * 100) would push them all into 1 array.

Comment: I pushes _one_ element into the array. So, do that _multiple_ times within your loop then. The part where you initialize `newArray` as an empty array, belongs _before_ that loop.

Comment: CBroe, Thanks for your help. Got it working, I'll add the the working code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know where your `yAxisValue` comes from but if your data is always in your `trainingInit` variable you can write your data entry for your chart as this:

```
datasets: [{
  label: 'Training',
  data: trainingInit.map((val) => (val*100))
  fill: false,
  borderColor: 'rgb(0, 119, 182)',
  backgroundColor: 'rgb(0, 119, 182)',
}]
```

Comment: LeeLenalee, this also did the job. Thanks!